# Roblox leaderstats not saving

Tags: roblox, luau

Ive been trying to make a game and somewhat successfully coded most of the game beside the dataStore saving. i'm unsure why it wont save as i've re-coded it many times and still isnt working

```
local clickDataStore = dataStoreService:GetDataStore("clickDataStore")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", plr)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local clicks = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    clicks.Name = "Clicks"

    local clickData
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        clickData = clickDataStore:GetAsync(plr.UserId.."-clicks")
    end)

    if success then
        clicks.Value = clickData
        print("Data Successfully Loaded")
    else
        print("There was an error.")
        warn(errormessage)
    end
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
    local success, errormessage = pcall(function()
        clickDataStore:SetAsync(plr.UserId.."-clicks", plr.leaderstats.Clicks.Value)
    end)

    if success then
        print("Data Successfully Saved")
    else
        print("There was an error.")
        warn(errormessage)
    end
end)
```

Comment: Are you testing on studio?